# Meaning of Blessing Pills

Tags: refuge

After taking refuge within the Karma Kagyu tradition, I got "blessing pills". I have no idea, by which occasion I should take them, how they are manufactured and in which historical, cultural and ritualistic context they are embed. The answer I got where not helpful.

Comment: [This article](https://www.mdpi.com/2077-1444/10/4/282/htm) details the tradition of Black Pills in  Karma Kagyü.